# How to call javascript function with flash/actionscript 3

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I want to call my `update(id)` javascript function from my flash menu with actionscript 3. How do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ExternalInterface.call.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;


ExternalInterface.call('update', id);
```

Comment: This results in nothing... I'm using CS3 and the button handler works, but nothing is happening. Any reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function displayCurrentTime()
{
var date = new Date();
return date.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>
```

You can call this function just like you always would, but simply call it like you would any other kind of a getter function where you store the returned value as part of some variable:

```
var currentTime:string = ExternalInterface.call("displayCurrentTime()");
```

When this code runs, Flash will call the displayCurrentTime JavaScript function and store the returned value from it in the currentTime variable.